# Fantasy novel about a girl who poses as a boy to train as a knight?

Tags: story-identification

In the late 1980s, I read a young adult novel, or series of novels, about a teenage girl that posed as a boy so she could attend a boys’ school to train to become a knight.

I thought the story took place in Ursula K. Le Guin‘s Earthsea world, but I was wrong. I’m rereading that series now and see that the book is unrelated, though it has a similar feel but no magic, that I remember.

Comment: If it's got no magic in it, what about it makes it 'fantasy'?

Comment: You could improve this question by going through the checklists [here](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9335/how-to-ask-a-good-story-id-question) and editing in any relevant info you can think to add. For example, what was her name? Why did they need knights? Was there an enemy? Why did she want to become a knight? Was there a love interest? Were the novels geared toward older teens or younger audiences? What did the book cover look like?

Comment: This question inspired me to ask [another one](https://literature.stackexchange.com/q/23407/17) (not fantasy, but again involving a girl posing as a boy who was assistant/squire to a knight).

Comment: @Valorum - I read that as "no magic _that I remember_" - that is, there is magic in Ursula Le Guin's books, but not the kind of magic that OP remembers from the other series.

Comment: @Valorum Non-human races, perhaps? Or just a fictional wish-fulfillment environment, maybe.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

This is *[Alanna: The First Adventure](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/13831.Alanna)* (1984) by Tamora Pierce.

> Alanna looked around and checked the hall for servants. “Tomorrow he gives us the letters for the man who trains the pages and the people at the convent. You can imitate his writing, so you can do new letters, saying we’re twin boys. “You go to the convent. Say in the letter that you’re to be a sorcerer. The Daughters of the Goddess are the ones who train young boys in magic, remember? When you’re older, they’ll send you to the priests. And I’ll go to the palace and learn to be a knight!”

Comment: As noted in Valorum's quoted summary, there is magic, but Alanna has no gift for it. She does have a magic sword and (later) a cat and a stone that sees through magic, both gifts from a goddess.

Comment: Thanks! I think that’s it! I don’t remember there subplot about her brother going to the convent, but his name “Thom” and the rest sound familiar.

Comment: @ChrisPeterson: Good news, she's written several books in the Tortall series, including a follow-up involving the first girl to try to become a knight openly as a woman.

Comment: No idea why the quote in this answer has the additional detail that Thom disguises himself as a girl. That's not in the linked description and as far as I remember, it's also not correct.

Comment: Also: Alanna does have a gift for magic, learns to use it and it plays a rather important role, contrary to what FuzzyBoots wrote.

Comment: @BlindKungFuMaster - I've swapped it out for a book quote

Comment: @Valorum - Her use of magic is perhaps more minimal in the first book, but she has magic.

Comment: @Adamant - I never said she didn't.

Comment: @BlindKungFuMaster: Ah, I must have misremembered. It has been a while. I read through the books as a child.